# missing fonts in photoshop

Tags: fonts, photoshop-script

I know that you can return the number of installed fonts in JavaScript with:

```
alert(app.fonts.length)
```

Working on a script to find the missing fonts in a psd file which hinges off this fact. Let's assume that the files are very large and consists of 100+ layers nested of layersets within layersets. And the missing fonts are somewhere in that haystack.

However, I have just discovered that if Photoshop is launched with a .PSD file which has is missing a font, there will be a missing font error (not saying which font is missing; hence the script) but app.fonts.length will also include the missing font. What's the best way around this problem? In CS2, is there a way of returning the equivalent of system.fonts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CS5 and above you can use

```
app.fonts.refreshFonts()
```